# For which $ \alpha > 0 $ exists a unique solution to differential equation $x' = (x-\alpha)^\alpha$, for $x > \alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I recently stumbled into this initial value problem:

Determine all values of $\alpha > 0$ such that the IVP:

$
\begin{cases}
x' = f(x) \\
x( \alpha ) = 0
\end{cases}
$

where

$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    (x-\alpha)^\alpha & \text{for } x > \alpha \\
    0 & \text{for } x \leq \alpha
\end{cases} $

has a unique solution?

I am heavily confused. Should I see $ x $ as a function or as a variable since there are the requirements $ x > \alpha $ and $ x \leq \alpha $. If I look at $ x $ like a variable shouln't just $ x' = 1$. If that's the case I guess the problem wouldn't have any solutions at all. If I look at $ x $ like a function however, I don't know how to interpret the $ x > \alpha $ and $ x \leq \alpha $ conditions.

I would appreciate any efforts to explain the problem to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of working with $x(t)$, work with $t(x)$ which makes the problem simple

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What do you exactly mean? Is it using the inverse function of x(t). I don't see what you mean. Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Mr Leibovici, I assume it needs to make the substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your differential equation is $$x'(t)=f(x(t)).$$ The function on the right side is just a normal scalar function $$f(x)=\max(0,x-a)^a.$$

As $$f(x)=0~\text{ for }~x\in(-\infty,a],$$ which is trivially Lipschitz there, and the initial condition is given as $x(a)=0$, there will only ever be one solution for $a>0$.

Comment: Am I right in stating that $ x(t) = 0 $ is a solution for all $a$? And is $ x' = 1- e^{x-1} $ a correct solution for $ a = 1 $. And if so are there any other values of $ a > 0$ so that there are any other solutions?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to prove uniqueness. For $ a>1 $ I guess it is locally lipschitz. Thus unique. The problem is for $ 0< a< 1 $. Are there any tricks I can use?

Comment: If you were to start at $x(0)=a$, you would get arbitrarily many solutions, as you can branch off $x(t)\equiv a$ at any time. As for the solution (?) for $a=1$, it does not satisfy the ODE where $x(t)<1$, as in that region there are only constant solutions.

Comment: I think I finally understood it. Since $ x(a) = 0$ there is an $ \delta $ such that $ x(a+t) = 0 $ for $ |t| < \delta $. (Because $ x $ is differentiable thus continuous.) Since $ x(t) > 0 $ would imply that $ x'(t) > 0 $ which is only possible for $ x(t) > a > 0 $ already this is not possible. Similarly $ x(t) $ can't be decreasing since $ x'(t) = f(x(t)) \ge 0 $. Therefore, we can conclude that $ x(t) \equiv 0$ for all $ t $ and also for all $ a > 0$ and we do not get any other solutions for any $ a > 0$. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try the substitution $y=(x-\alpha)$. Therefore, we will have $(y+\alpha)^{'}=y^{\alpha}$. $y^{'}=y^{\alpha},\implies{\frac{dy}{y^{\alpha}}=dt},\implies{\frac{y^{-\alpha+1}}{{-\alpha+1}}=t+C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that for $ \alpha \ge 1 $, we have a unique solution since the substitution leads to $ y' = y^\alpha $ and $ y^\alpha $ has a continuous derivative and is therefore locally lipschitz. Thus the solution is unique according to the Picard-Lindelöf theorem. Thats your solution after some rearrangements. 
Where as for $ \alpha < 1 $ the lipschitz requirement doesn't hold and we could get different solutions. But how would you be able to obtain such solution if it exists. Since usually I calculated one and guessed the other. But I can't guess a solution.

Comment: Also is the case distinction of $ x < \alpha $ and $ x \leq \alpha $ for f just say that if $ x(t)$ is less than $ \alpha $ the derivative should be 0?

Comment: @user007, If $x=\alpha$, therefore, $(x-\alpha)=0$ and $t=-C$. The main is $\alpha\ne{1}$.

Comment: I am so sorry. I just saw that the starting condition is wrong. It states $ x( \alpha ) = 0 $ in my problem at hand. (I changed it in the question.)
I am so sorry. How does that effect the solution and what do you mean with $ x = \alpha $ and the main is $ \alpha \neq 1 $.

Comment: @user007, If $(x-\alpha)=0\implies\frac{(\alpha-\alpha)}{-\alpha+1}=0$ and $(t+C)=\frac{(\alpha-\alpha)}{-\alpha+1}=0$. If $\alpha={1}\implies{(t+C)}\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: So for $ \alpha =1 $
 we would have the solution $ x'=1 - e^{x-1} $
. And that would also be the unique solution right? Also for $ \alpha >1 $
 it's locally lipschitz thus unique. My question would be how I can prove or disprove the uniqueness for $ \alpha <1 $
.